# Calling sidebars in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am trying to use two different sidebars for both pages and posts.

For that I have used the following condition to test if it is a page (if yes call `"sidebar-15"` otherwise call `"blog"`).

```
<?php 
     if (is_page()){
      dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-15' );
     }
     else {
      get_sidebar( 'blog' );
     }
?>
```

But, on pages it is still calling `blog side bar`. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: In what file you're checking this condition ? `index.php` ?

Comment: in content-page.php and page.php

Comment: You code seems correct. Try the reverse condition with is_single(), it might help you debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[get_sidebar function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)

```
<?php get_sidebar( $name_of_sidebar_file ); ?>
```

for example:
files: sidebar-right.php and sidebar-left.php
calling:

```
get_sidebar('right');
get_sidebar('left');
```

Comment: i actually aware of how to call side bar .. but here my concern is calling different sidebars by checking whether it is a page or blog post. if it is page then one sidebar if it is blog then another sidebar.

Comment: i see, you can edit page.php to include your specific sidebar, otherwise and elsewhere it will be the default